# Can the manifest file be changed

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

In short the policys on my chromebook have been changed to keep me from adding extension to chrome so ive gone onto chrome-stats.com and download a extension in crx but when i attempt to add it, it appears says its blocked, so what i want to do is change the id in the manifest json to make it appear as the allowed extension ids.
This is one of the ids that are not blacklisted
hdhinadidafjejdhmfkjgnolgimiaplp

btw linux is blocked by administration and zip files cannot be unpacked into the extension manager